# Ruby on Rails naming convention in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the RoR view You often need to display lists of some models. If You use instance variables for this, like `@people` and `countries`, RubyMine IDE will warn You that You should use **at most** two instance variables in the view.

So let's say You will wrap those in a hash, like:

```
view_params = { people: @people, countries: @countries }
```

I know naming is very important in RoR. Is there any **naming convention** for such hash, which I called view_params (in Django they call it *context* I guess), or **good practice** how to deal with this problem?

Comment: You can't change the warning level/trigger point? In any case, there are any number of ways to handle this: view objects is probably one of the most common. This is more or less what you've done, but in an ad-hoc manner. The testing is essentially the same, though.

Comment: It's more about making code clean and following good practices, I can always change warning trigger, like You said - but if it shows up, it means that it's not recommended, that's why I ask.

Answer (score 3):

It's a stupid rule. Turn off the rule in your IDE.

Stick to the better rule - "Methods can be no longer than five lines of code." If you find your controller methods becoming longer than five lines because you're building too many instance variable - then package them up. But if you can create all the instance variables you want in about 5 lines of code, then that's fine.

If you look at the example in [Sandi Metz Rules For Developers](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers), all they've done is package the instance variables into another object. Is there really a good reason why having two instance variables associated with a controller instance is worse than making them belong to a new object instance?

For me:

```
def index
  @foo = Foo.get_some
  @bar = Bar.get_some
end
```

Is cleaner and simpler than:

```
class FooBar
  attr_reader :foo, :bar
  def initialize(foo, bar)
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
  end
end

class FooBarController

  def index
    foo = Foo.get_some
    bar = Bar.get_some
    @foo_bar = FooBar.new(foo, bar)
  end

end
```

Comment: In a case like that, where you expect that to be the final product without any changes, then that's probably the best way to go. But if you expect more changes to be made in the future that will require more variables and methods that are specific to the view, then facades are more effective in the long run, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm a firm believer in not making things complicated until you need to. If the simple solution becomes a problem with a later revision, then it should be refactored at that point, but not before - and never just in case.

Comment: I'm glad You suggested the solution in very descriptive way. I personally think that lean Controller with small methods is the way to go, and I need to further investigate the [Sandi Metz rules](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers).

Comment: @UncleChris Hmmmmm. The fat controller / fat model debate is a bit of a bug bear to me. It misses the point. NO CLASS SHOULD BE FAT. If any class gets too big, you should think about how to better break down the functionality into other objects. It is irrelevant if that class is a model or a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-active record ruby class instead of a hash. One instance variable is probably best. See facade pattern: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers